# Moving button like assistive touch

Tags: ios, assistive

Hi I want to move a uibutton where even I want in my app like we have Assistive touch in iphone so as a same I want that kind of button in my app..Is it possible to do that If so please help out with code are some links for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is asked so many times.... here is answer

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        button.frame.x = touchlocation.x;
        button.frame.y = touchlocation.y;
    }
```

Comment: Ur answer is correct but with my move button is not moving...it has move along with my touch

Comment: In my page I have table view and another view How I can show that button on top of that view like when even I click on that button some action show perform ...sorry I am new to IOS